# Query Active directory and Scrape Company profile from same field

Tags: c#, active-directory

So this is in reference to a project I am in the middle of.

I have hard coded this to just search my name so far - but I want to be able to search:

AD
Our internal site
and eventually our authorization software (this will be at a later time)

I have written the portion that scrapes our internal page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

namespace Get_Source_Code
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = urlTextBox.Text;


            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            var rawStream = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            var myBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            rawStream = rawStream.Replace("<br>", " ");
            rawStream = rawStream.Replace("<br />", " ");
            myBuilder.AppendLine("Employee Name : " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_DisplayFullName\">", "</span>"));
            myBuilder.AppendLine("Title: " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_Title\">", "</span>"));
            myBuilder.AppendLine("Location : " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_Location\">", "</span>"));
            myBuilder.AppendLine("Department : " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_Department\">", "</span>"));
            myBuilder.AppendLine("Group: " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_Group\">", "</span>"));
            myBuilder.AppendLine("Office Phone : " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_IntPhoneNumber\">", "</span>"));
            myBuilder.AppendLine("Mobile Phone : " + rawStream.Between("<span id=\"Label_BusMobile\">", "</span>"));
            richTextBox1.Text = myBuilder.ToString();

        }

        private void urlTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public static class StringHelper
    {
        public static string Between(this string source, string left, string right)
        {
            var result = (new Regex(left + "(.*?)" + right)).Match(source).Groups[1].ToString();
            if (result == "") result = null;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at the following answer "[Quick way to retrieve user information Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456523/quick-way-to-retrieve-user-information-active-directory)"

and looks to be pointing me in the right direction. But I'm still green on this and unsure how to approach this.

Especially because I am trying to get this all from one query.

Comment: So is the info you want already on the webpage you're scraping?  Is the page you're scraping the page that pulls that info from AD?  I'm confused as to where AD ties into what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I did not structure this question well and I apologize.

I want to scrape the website AND active directory and dump the info on a RichTextField. 

This is so that we do not need to go to multiple locations for a users info.